# Units in curvilinear (e.g. polar) coordinate systems

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, units, dimensional-analysis

Let’s say that someone measures the distance from a rocket to the earth's surface to be equal to $h=10[m]$ (meters) at time $t=5[s]$ (seconds) (in a [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)) - so our vector with data from physical measurements is the following:

$$V=( 10[m], 5 [s])$$

I want to transform this vector to a [Polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) using general formulas (from this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Orthogonal_curvilinear_coordinates_in_3_dimensions) - this is very important for me - because my real case is more complicated in 3d with the nontypical curvilinear coordinate system  - but for clearness and simplicity I use the 2d case). My transformation formulas from polar to Cartesian coordinates are the following:

$$x=r\cos\varphi$$
$$y=r\sin\varphi$$

first based on point position vector $\mathbf{r} = (x[m], y[s])= x\mathbf{e}_x[m] + y\mathbf{e}_y[s]$ I want to calculate vetors $\mathbf{h}_1=\partial \mathbf{r}/\partial r $ and $\mathbf{h}_2=\partial \mathbf{r}/\partial \varphi $  as follows

$$\mathbf{h}_1 = \cos\varphi \mathbf{e}_x[m] + \sin\varphi \mathbf{e}_y[s] $$
$$\mathbf{h}_2 = r\sin\varphi \mathbf{e}_x[m] - r\cos\varphi \mathbf{e}_y[s] $$

And next step - here is **problem**: I need to calculate lengths: $h_1=|\mathbf{h}_1|$, $h_2=|\mathbf{h}_2|$, so I get

$$h_1=|\mathbf{h}_1| = \sqrt{\cos^2\varphi[m^2] + \sin^2\varphi[s^2]}$$
$$h_2=|\mathbf{h}_2| = \sqrt{r^2\sin^2\varphi[m^2] + r^2\cos^2\varphi[s^2]}$$

But the theoretically proper values for the polar case should be $h_1=1$ and $h_1=r$ - as you can see from the fact that each coordinate has a different unit "blocking" me to get the proper result.

**Question 1**: How to deal with units when we change the coordinate system?

**Question 2**: I notice that in the polar coordinate system there is also another (fundamental?) problem: we have radius $r$ (meters are probably proper unit here) and angle $\varphi$ - but what unit should there be for the angle? (!) (this is especially visible in an example similar to the one above but where we have meters instead of seconds)

### Update

Here is simple case which shows also the problem I describe above - lets try to convert vector $V=( 10[m], 5 [s])$ to polar coordinates using direct formulas

$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
$$\varphi = \operatorname{arctg}(x/y)$$

Lets start calculations:

$$r = \sqrt{(10[m])^2 + (5[s])^2}=\sqrt{100[m^2] + 25[s^2]} = ? $$

different units don't allow to calculate sum under last square root (even if such operation was allowed - what will be the unit of $r$ ?).

Comment: The wiki article deals only with spatial coordinates. Do you really want to work with temporal and spatial coordinates? The subject changes to special relativity in this case.

Comment: Yes - I want to work with different units for each coordinate (however time is not mandatory - it can be also e.g. meters [m] and kilograms [kg])

Comment: You can't add meters to seconds. In two dimensional Cartesinan coordinates, the velocity reads $(v_{x}, v_{y})$ and both components are in meters per second.

Comment: $V=((10m), 5(s))$ What quantity is $V$ supposed to be? I can’t see how what you are doing makes sense.

Comment: @saad vector $V$ is NOT velocity - but it contains data measured using two different units. But if "time" is problem for you - then lets measure rocket weight (it loose fuel) so $V=( 10[m], 10000[kg] )$ and now - let's transform this data to polar coordinate system - how to deal with units?

Comment: @G.Smith $V$ is not speed. It only contains data which I need to transform to polar coordinate system. The key point that unit of each coordinate are different. I need to transform that data to polar coordinates - but how to deal with units in that case? (if there is problem with time for you, then lets suppose that I measure rockert weight (because it loose fuel) and I have $V=(10[m], 10000[kg])$ - as you can see, the problem still exist when I want to transform it to polar coordinate system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that your vector does not have meaning in a polar coordinate system, I'll show a question that is simple to answer about a vector $(x,y)$ when both $x$ and $y$ are lengths and impossible to answer when $x$ is a length and $y$ is time. Consider the angle that the line joining the origin and $(x,y)$ makes when measured from the positive x-axis. Is this angle greater than 45$^\circ$? If $x$ and $y$ are both positive and $y>x$, then yes. Now, if $x$ is a length and $y$ is time, how do you answer the question of whether $x>y$? Length and time are non-comparable, so the question has no meaning and no meaningful angle can be assigned to your vector.

For any mathematical quantity, there are operations that make sense and those that don't. Any two numbers can be divided unless the divisor is zero, in which case the answer is most likely meaningless for the problem being solved. In quantities with units, there are even more restrictions. You can only add quantities with units that have the same dimensions (length and length, time and time, etc). Three feet plus a meter makes sense. Two meters plus five joules does not. As you found when calculating the length of your vector, the quantity $m^2 + s^2$ does not have a clear meaning because the differing dimensions make addition meaningless.

You are perfectly free to work with your vector in its current form. But, because the components of the vector have different dimensions, certain mathematical operations are not valid. In this case, adding the squares of the components is invalid, which makes finding the length of the vector invalid, which makes polar coordinates invalid.

I answered a more general question related to this [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423665/dimensional-analysis-of-vectors-possible/).

Comment: Brilliant answer - deep an simple - thank you:)

Comment: I have following question: lets assume that we have some equation (e.g Navier-Stokes) - and want to find it's form in cylindrical rotating coordinate system - as far I know the scientists use this roatatein coord system. But using you argument it look that there is some problem there ?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski There is no problem with using a different coordinate system, though the equations will come out looking different. For example, the length of a vector in cartesian coordinates ($[x,y,z]$), is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. The length of a vector in cylindrical coordinates ($[r, \theta, z]$), is $\sqrt{r^2 + z^2}$. In spherical coordinates ($[r, \theta, \phi]$), the length is $r$. When converting bewteen coordinate systems, you have to make sure the units stay consistent. It is easy to convert a set of distances to a set of angles and vice versa; not so much distances and times.

Comment: you are right - but in ROTATING frame of reference in our transofrmation we also use time. Our new coordinates (formulas) depend on time... for example look on [this article](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.654.1059&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on equations 8-10. And my question is... what about units for x^1 and x^2 (and general formulas in my main question))? (whole article is about time-dependent coordinate systems - and they are not first who do it(!))

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski The only difference in time-dependent coordinates is that the functions that transform old coordinates into new has a parameter for time. The output quantity of the function had better have compatible units: distances have units of length, angles have units of length ratios, etc. In equation 10, $\xi^1$ and $\xi^2$ both have units of distance.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski The use of $\tau$ inside the sine and cosine functions in equation 10 is a bit shady, but it works if you imagine that the intended roation speed is 1 rad/sec (the input to trig functions should be unitless, so the actual expression is $\cos\omega\tau$ where $\omega = 1$ rad/sec). It was omitted to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 1):

Your rocket problem contains one spatial dimension. So unless you are using special relativistic four vector notation, I don't see why you should represent its position in spacetime as you have. Your system is therefore one-dimensional and not two-dimensional.

$r$ has the unit of length and $\varphi$ the unit of angle, i.e. the radian. However, distances are to be measured in meters. Perhaps you are confused about the fact that in 2D polar coordinates, one coordinate has the dimension of length and the other is dimensionless. This isn't a problem, really. Starting from Cartesian coordinates,

$$ \mathbf{r} =  r \cos \varphi \mathbf{e}_{x} [m] + r \sin \varphi \mathbf{e}_{y} [m] $$

This is because $r$ has units of $m$ and $\varphi$ or $\cos \varphi$ or $\sin \varphi$ are dimensionless.

Also, remember that even when you switch to a different coordinate system, the units have to be consistent. For example, if you wish to calculate distances,

$$ d\mathbf{r} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial r} dr + \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial \varphi} d\varphi  \implies ds^{2} =  d\mathbf{r}. d\mathbf{r} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial r}. \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial r} dr^{2} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial \varphi}.\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial \varphi} d\varphi^{2} + 2 \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial \varphi} . \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial r} d \varphi dr$$

Now plug in your expressions for $\mathbf{h}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{h}_{2}$ and you will get

$$ ds^{2} = dr^{2} + r^{2} d \varphi^{2}$$

Notice that this has exactly the units of distance squared, as you would want it to have. The coefficients $1$ and $r^{2}$ in front of the differentials squared are known as the components of the $\textit{metric tensor}$. This tells you how much distance you cover if you go radially from $r$ to $r+dr$ and your angle changes from $\varphi$ to $\varphi + d\varphi$

Comment: You give answer to different question than my. Don't confuse vector $V$ in my question with speed. My original case is more complicated that this 2d example - don't change it - but If time is problem for you then lets change question an lets measure rocket weight (it loose fuel so it will be lighter) $V=( 10[m], 10000 [kg] )$. I know that in case where units are the same for botch coordinates is no problem - bu I ask on case when two units are different - how to deal with that?

Comment: *"when you switch to a different coordinate system, the units have to be consisten"* - can you give some reference to this information (with proof)?

Comment: There is also another problem: your opinion about coordinate system consistency - actually I can make transformation to polar coords $V^*\approx (11.18, 26.56)$ - but in first step I drop units, then transform dimensionless data, and get dimension-less result (which I need for e.g. visualistation... ) - so it is possible - but the only problem is witch $V^*$ UNITS (I can of course temporar drop them, and remember to set the again during reverse transformation to cartesian - but yes... this is some lack of notation or someting - how to deal with it in formal way to not "lose unit information")

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a cartesian vector has a magnitude and a direction, and the magnitude carries the units. This means that a cartesian vector should have all elements in the same dimensional space.

For example $\boldsymbol{r} = (5\text{ [m]}) \pmatrix{ -1\sqrt{2} \\ 1\sqrt{2} }$

To take a measurement you can use the identity metric $\mathbf{1}$ to do

$$ \ell = \sqrt{ \boldsymbol{r} \cdot \mathbf{1}\, \boldsymbol{r} } = (5\text{ [m]})\sqrt{ \left(-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2} = 5\text{ [m]}$$

The vector described in the question isn't a cartesian vector. It is kind-of a state vector. It describes the state of the object. A more complete state vector would be

$$ \boldsymbol{V} = \pmatrix{ t\text{ [s]} \\ h\text{ [m]} \\ v\text{ [m/s]}   } $$

The state vector is useful in describing the evolution of a system as a differential equation $$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{V} = \mathbf{A} \boldsymbol{V} + \boldsymbol{b} $$

Consider the example below of a mass $m$ hanging down from a spring with stiffness $k$, under gravity $g$.

$$\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \pmatrix{ t \\ y \\ v } = \begin{bmatrix} 0  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -\tfrac{k}{m} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{ t \\ y \\ v   } + \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ -g}  = \pmatrix{1 \\ v \\ -\tfrac{k}{m} y -g}$$ which collapses to the system of equations $\dot{y}=v$ and $\dot{v}=-\tfrac{k}{m} y-g$.

You cannot use state vectors to take measurements unless you define some kind of metric. For example, the height metric might be something like $$ \mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ & 1 & \\ & & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$ which is used to *extract* the distance from the ground

$$ \text{(distance)} = \sqrt{ \pmatrix{ t \\ y \\ v }^\top \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ & 1 & \\ & & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{ t \\ y \\ v } } = \sqrt{y^2} = |y| $$

**The key here is that $\mathbf{M}$ acts like some kind of ruler, telling us which component of the vector to disregard, which to include and by how much.** Without that a measurement cannot be made. The metric takes care of the units such as the measurement taken is valid.

Another example would a time metric which includes a reference speed $v_{\rm ref}$ $$\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & \tfrac{1}{v_{\rm ref}} & \\ & & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ which is used to extract a time measurement

$$ \text{(time)} = \sqrt{ \pmatrix{ t \\ y \\ v }^\top \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & \tfrac{1}{v_{\rm ref}} & \\ & & 0 \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{ t \\ y \\ v } } = \sqrt{ t^2 + \left( \tfrac{y}{v_{\rm ref}} \right)^2} = \ldots \text{[s]}$$

As you can imagine, the above has *consistent* units of time.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone considering using this sort of spacetime, relevant posts in the site include:

- [Galilean spacetime interval?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368680/galilean-spacetime-interval/368714)
- [Why Galilean spacetime is not $\mathbb{E}^4$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163560/why-galilean-spacetime-is-not-mathbbe4)

Perhaps this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00726944) by Artz ([e-print](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00726944.pdf)), can also be of interest.