# How to read double integrator equations?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

From what I understand, double integrator is a model where some entity can move according to some speed, which depends on the acceleration force exerted on the entity.

If someone would ask me to represent such a model, with $x$ the position of the entity, $v$ its velocity, and $a$ its acceleration, I would write it down as simply :

$$ \dot{x} = v $$
$$ \ddot{x} = a $$

However these do not seem to be the same relations as given by the Wikipedia page (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_integrator). Maybe I'm having trouble with the notation. What do the following equations, meant to represent a double integrator system **in a single dimension**, mean exactly?

$$ \ddot{q} = u(t) $$
$$ y = q(t) $$

$u$ is described as the control input, which I assume is the acceleration, and $q$ the output, which is the entity's position? So, what is $y$? It seems to be equal to $q$, so what is its use here?

Comment: I think you're confusing a **control system** , which involves feedback, with the equations which define the motion of an object when a force is applied (if no force, then $\ddot{x} = 0$

Comment: In any case (control system or not), I'd like to understand the equations from the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

**The wikipedia article is inconsistent in notation and in form.**

Also, the article contains constraint equations between the degrees of freedom which further complicates the notation. You don't have such considerations for a 1 DOF problem.

So take your example, with $n=1$ DOF and consider the following quantities

- The generalized coordinates are vector of $n$ values

  $$\boldsymbol{q} = \pmatrix{x} \tag{1}$$
- The differential equation is given in terms of the degrees of freedom as a system of $n$ equations

  $$ \ddot{\boldsymbol{q}} = \boldsymbol{\rm f}(t, \boldsymbol{q}, \dot{\boldsymbol{q}}) \tag{2}$$

  $$ \ddot{x} = {\rm f}(t,x,\dot{x}) $$
- As an ODE the above is of second order and it is setup as the integration of two variables (double integrator) in order to be solved. As a system of two first order ODEs the above is expressed with $2n$ equations.

  $$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}  \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{q} \\ \boldsymbol{\dot{q}} } = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{\dot q} \\ \boldsymbol{\rm f}(t,\boldsymbol{q},\boldsymbol{\dot{q}})  } \tag{3}$$
  $$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \pmatrix{x \\ v} = \pmatrix{v \\ {\rm f}(t,x,v)} $$
- More formally with a state vector $\boldsymbol{x} = \pmatrix{ \boldsymbol{q} \\ \boldsymbol{\dot q}}$ the above system of equations is brought into a more canonical form which is what the article *should* have shown

  $$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{\rm u}(t, \boldsymbol{x}) \tag{4}$$

  $$ \begin{aligned} \dot{x} & = v \\
      \dot{v} & = {\rm f}(t,x,v) \end{aligned}$$

  <sub>Note that [the state vector isn't a real vector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/572360/392) in terms of physics, but rather a mathematical construct.</sub>
- The system can also describe constraints which tie together different degrees of freedom and their derivatives

  $$ \boldsymbol{y} = \boldsymbol{\rm g}(t, \boldsymbol{x}) \tag{5} $$

  but this does not apply in your case.
- All of the above become a little more formal when expressed in terms of linear algebra as a DAE system ([differential and algebraic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-algebraic_system_of_equations))

  $$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{x} = \mathbf{A} \boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{b} \tag{6} $$
  $$ \boldsymbol{0} = \mathbf{G} \boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{c} \tag{7} $$

Comment: What is DOF (degree of freedom?) and ODE?

Comment: Sorry, yes. DOF = Degrees of Freedom and ODE is ordinary differential equation.